# Why Python BeautifulSoup object is callable? Where is the definition?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, callable

bb and cc in the following code are equal, why is this the case? soup is an object, why it can accept another parameter 'a' here? Is soup('a') here a function call or another class/object initialization? If it is a function call, I did not find a **call** definition in the class. I hope the question is clear. thanks.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("<html><a href='bla'>sss</a><a>cc</a></html>", 'html.parser')
bb = soup('a')
cc = soup.find_all('a')
```

Comment: In practice, should we always prefer soup('a') over soup.find_all('a') if they give same results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, actually there's no difference, calling the `tag` is an `alias` for `findAll`

Check [source code](https://github.com/waylan/beautifulsoup/blob/480367ce8c8a4d1ada3012a95f0b5c2cce4cf497/bs4/element.py#L980-L984)

```py
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """Calling a tag like a function is the same as calling its
    find_all() method. Eg. tag('a') returns a list of all the A tags
    found within this tag."""
    return self.find_all(*args, **kwargs)
```

The reason why almost of `developers` use `findAll` because it's actually more readable.

Comment: thanks a lot, did not realized __call__ could be defined under tag class, thought it must be under BeautifulSoup __init__.